# My XML is not exporting elements. Why?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I've been working on a tool to convert data into the Collada .DAE format, which is XML based. Unfortunately, one thing has been stopping me: My exported XML doesn't have any of my elements!

Here's the code. I've made it easy-to-read so that you don't have to go through as much of the trouble of reading it.

```
public class DAEExport {
    private static boolean alreadyConstructed = false;
    private static Document doc = null;
    private static Element root = null;
    private static Element lib_images_base_element = null;
    private static Element lib_geometry_base_element = null;
    private static Element lib_control_base_element = null;
    private static Element lib_visual_scene_base_element = null;

    public static void AppendData() {
         //Normally this method would have the data to append as its args, but I'm not worried about that right now.
         //Furthermore, ASSUME THIS RUNS ONLY ONCE (It runs once in the test code I'm using to run this method)! I know that it won't work if called multiple times, as the below variables for the document builder and such wouldn't exist the second time around
         try {
             if (!alreadyConstructed) {
                 alreadyConstructed = true;
                 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                 Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();

                 Element rootElement = document.createElement("SomeGenericElement");
                 rootElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Generic test contents");

                 document.appendChild(rootElement);

                 doc = document;
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    public static void Build(File _out) {
        try {
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);


            transformer.transform(source, result);

            alreadyConstructed = false;
            doc = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so here's my problem: Despite adding those elements to the document by calling `AppendData()`, then calling `Build()` to print the data, I only get the following data:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` - No elements. Just the basic header. This is it.

I don't know if it's because of some silly mistake that I've been oblivious to for the past amount of time, or something else. Any answers as to why my elements disappeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your `doc` object is not being passed from `AppendData()` method to `Build()` method. All `Build()` uses is an empty doc from declaration: `doc = null`. Hence, your outcome is empty of nodes (TransformFactory adds the XML header).

Consider returning the `doc` object from `AppendData()` to be available at class level for other method (do note you change the void to returned object type). You then redefine `doc` and pass it into `Build()`:

```
public static Document AppendData() {
    ...
    doc = document
    return(doc)
}
```

Alternatively, call `Build()` inside `AppendData`, passing `doc` as a parameter:

```
public static void AppendData() {
    ...
    doc = document
    Build(doc, outfile)
}

public static void Build(Document doc, File _out) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm still kind of confused why doc was still `null`. I'm aware that it _could have_ been null, but if I called AppendData() would it no longer be null, hence the `doc = document` line?

Comment: Edit: I changed it from `Document document = docBuilder.newDocument();` to `doc = docBuilder.newDocument()`, and also changed `private static Document doc = null;` to `private static Document doc;` and it seems to work now. Still a bit confused as to why this worked and the other way didn't.

Comment: Great that it worked out. And again your earlier setup did manipulate `doc` but only in that context, `AppendData()`. As soon as method completes without a return the manipulated `doc` object is no longer available. `Build()` only sees the initialized `doc` (not manipulated one) with null value.